# Array and methods?

Tags: java

I'm doing a task for a course in Java programming and I'm not sure how the following thing is working? The method below takes the value from an array and a integer. The integer should be added to the array and then be used outside the method in other methods and so on, but how could this work when the method has no return for the new content of the array? There is a void in the method? Have I missed something? Preciate some help? Is there something about pointers?

```
public static void makeTransaction(int[] trans, int amount);
```

Comment: What does `added to the array` mean exactly?

Comment: "The integer should be added to the array and then be used outside the method in other methods and so on" you will need to be more specific, your question is extremely vague.

Comment: If int amount has a value of 200, I want to add that to the array in a new index of the array trans. Perhaps there is an explanation below?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in Java are objects. If you modify the `trans` array inside the method, the changes will be reflected outside of it<sup>1</sup>. Eg:

```
public static void modify(int[] arr)
{
    arr[0] = 10;
}

public static void main(...) 
{
    int x = {1, 2, 3};
    System.out.println(x[0]); // prints 1

    modify(x);
    System.out.println(x[0]); // now it prints 10

}
```

Note that native arrays can't be dynamically resized in Java. You will have to use something like [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) if you need to do that. Alternatively you can change the return type to `int[]` and return a new array with the new element "appended" to the old array:

```
public static int[] makeTransaction(int[] trans, int amount)
{
    int[] new_trans = Arrays.copyOf(trans, trans.length + 1);
    new_trans[trans.length] = amount;

    return new_trans;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It is also worth noting that as objects, array **references are passed by value**, so the following code has no effect whatsoever outside of the method:

```
public void no_change(int[] arr)
{
    arr = new int[arr.length];
}
```

Comment: They are not just object-like. They **are** Objects. int[] instanceof Object is true.

Comment: Aha, if I add 200 to the array trans inside the method, then the same array trans is "updated" with 200 when I use later in the code?

Comment: @3D-kreativ Depends on what you mean by "add." You can't add new elements to the array, but you can modify the contents of existing elements.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I't more like modify the array trans that has a index from 0 to 9. Can't I add new values to one of the index from 0 to 9? Or must there be values from the beginning in all index that I just replace with new values? ArrayList is not allowed to use in this task.

Comment: You can modify arbitrary elements from in an array; as long as they are in range. (`[0, array.length)`)

Comment: Hmmm, could you explain that please?

Comment: @3D-kreativ You can modify any element in an array as long as it already exists. So if you have `int[] arr = new int[10]`, you can modify `arr[i]` for any value of `i` between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add anything to an array. Java arrays have a fixed length. So indeed, what you want to do is impossible. You might make the method return an `int[]` array, but it would be a whole new array, containing all the elements of the initial one + the amount passed as argument.

If you want to add something to an array-like structure, use an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to keep the method signature as is?

Also, can you be a bit more specific.  When you say "the integer should be added to the array", are you referring to the `amount` argument?  If so, then how is that amount added?  Do we place it somewhere in the array or is it placed at the end, thus extending the array's length?

As far as pointers go, Java's pointers are implicit, so if you don't have a strong enough knowledge of the language, then it might not be so clear to you.  Anyways, I believe that Java methods usually will pass objects by reference, and primitives by value.  But, even that isn't entirely true.  If you were to assign your object argument to new object, when the method terminates, the variable that you passed to the method is the same after the method executed as it was before.  But, if you were to change the argument's member attributes, then when the method terminated those attributes values will be the same as they were inside of the method.

Anyways, back to your question, I believe that will work because an array is an object.  So,  if you were to do the following:

```
    public static void makeTransaction(int[] trans, int amount)
    {
        trans[0] = amount;
    }

//  static int i;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        int[] trans = {0,1,3};
        makeTransaction(trans, 10);
        for(int i = 0; i<trans.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(trans[i]);
        }
    }
```

The output of the array will be:

> 10
>   1
>   3

But, **watch this**.  What if I decided to implement `makeTransaction` like so:

```
public static void makeTransaction(int[] trans, int amount)
{
    trans[0] = amount;
    trans = new int[3];
}
```

What do you think that the output will be?  Will it be set to all zero's or will be the same as it was before?  The answer is that the output will be the same as it was before.  This ties in to what I was saying earlier.

I might've assigned that pointer to a new object in memory, but your copy of the pointer inside of the main method remains the same.  It still points to the same place in memory as it did before.   When the `makeTransaction` method terminates, the `new int[3]` object that I created inside of it is available for garbage collection.  The original array remains intact.  So, when people say that Java passes objects by reference, it's really more like passing objects' references by value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for code and help. The task I'm doing is like an ATM machine. The int amount is the deposit or the opposit whit a negative value. I should also use other methods that finds the index number of the array where I van place the deposit and I should also use a method that moves all previous deposits to give place for the new deposit. Hmm, it's a little bit complicated, but perhaps it could be solved with the help of all code and info above. Thanks!